# EDL Shader in Potree Viewer with orthographic mode

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I have a problem with EDL Shader in [Potree Viewer](https://github.com/potree/potree). While it works correct with perspective mode, I am in need to use orthographic mode in my project.
Please see the GIF and the example at the bottom.

There is a problem with EDL Renderer that does not work correctly with an orthographic mode. The problem appears when you zoom the point cloud. At some point, shadows disappear and we lose the depth perception.

You should be able to reproduce this on any public example. Just remember to set the orthographic mode from the Tools panel in the sidebar.

I would really appreciate any help.

---

You can see how it looks like on this **GIF**:
https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-9e188b342d1c.gif

The **example** I used in GIF is available here: http://www.potree.org/potree/examples/lion_laz.html

---

You can see Potree shaders here: https://github.com/potree/potree/tree/develop/src/materials/shaders

Also, navigation controls that manipulate position of the camera:
https://github.com/potree/potree/blob/develop/src/navigation/OrbitControls.js

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to looks like the EDL shading gets cut off at the same time that the camera's `near` plane is crossed. You can see this by switching between `perspective` and `ortho` view; shading ends at the same point when the particles no longer show in the perspective cam.

You could change [the `camera.near` value](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/cameras/OrthographicCamera.near) to something lower, I think you can even set it as a negative value on Ortho cams.

Comment: Good find. thank you. I tried changing camera.near but the problem is that the value already is -1000. I tried experimenting with different values (higher values, close to 0) but nothing worked for me.
I am also guessing, maybe the implementation of the fragment shader for EDL is wrong? I don't know much about shaders so it is quite difficult for me and as far as I know, there is no way to debug them.

Comment: So it looks like the camera moves closer and further away from the center in a "dolly" fashion. Maybe instead of moving it closer, you can change its `camera.zoom` value? Something like `camera.zoom = 2.0;` Then you can try 3.0, 4.0, etc... to see if that works. Also, don't forget to call `camera.updateProjectionMatrix();` after each change in zoom value.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I tried with updating the `camera.zoom` value to higher values (along with increasing point size) but again it didn't help - shadows are not rendered at all in that scenario.  
So, setting the `camera.near` value to something close to 0 seems to align the threshold where shadows stop working with the camera cutting the point cloud but I am not able to find a place where this value is generated for EDL renderer. I tried looking for `near` values everywhere and I was not able to find anything (I was experimenting with almost everything).